# Pixie Image Editor Integration with Ionic 3.X

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am looking to integrate Pixie Image Editor with Ionix 3.X. I try to install it using

`npm install "Path of source folder provided in package"`

It's showing installed "pixie": "file:pixie" in package.json but when I try to import it in "app.module.ts" using below statement get getting an error that 'pixie' does not exist.

> import { Pixie } from 'pixie';

Comment: try this `var pixie = require('pixie')`

Comment: @Najamussaqib Getting error Cannot find name 'require'.

Comment: include it where you import other dependencies.. at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> import * as pixie from "pixie"